# What does the Facebook Graph API v3.0 groups_access_member_info permission do?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

One of the new changes with version 3.0 is a new [`group_access_member_info`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v3.0#reference-groups_access_member_info) permission.  The stated intent is to 'Allow apps to get content posted in their group with user details', but there is no information on what exactly it gives you access to.

We have an app that needs access to the `from` field on posts and comments.  It sounds like this new permission might do that, but it doesn't seem to work.

Using the [graph api explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/) and our development application (Graph API Explorer app doesn't show any group information at all even with permissions for some reason) and giving it that permission doesn't seem to show anything that can't be accesses without the permission.

So I'm wondering what exactly the permission is supposed to give access to...  Is it something they're still working on?

I'm using a development version of our app and it allows me to request and receive those permissions, here's what's returned for `/me/permissions`:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "permission": "email",
      "status": "granted"
    },
    {
      "permission": "user_managed_groups",
      "status": "granted"
    },
    {
      "permission": "publish_to_groups",
      "status": "granted"
    },
    {
      "permission": "groups_access_member_info",
      "status": "granted"
    },
    {
      "permission": "public_profile",
      "status": "granted"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Yes, that’s what it is for. But it has to be granted by each individual user - you will only get `from` info for posts/comments made by people that granted your app that permission. (GAE probably shows nothing, because that app is “live” - but the ability to test permissions without review is only available for apps that are still in development mode.)

Comment: I am using a development version of our app, looking at a group I created and that I am an admin of, and looking at a post that I posted myself, but see no from field.  I can tell my access token has the `group_access_member_info` permission looking at the permissions returned by the javascript sdk...  So maybe it's just buggy and not working at the moment?

Comment: Yeah, I currently can’t seem to get it to work either.

Comment: Although this is an old post I found some information that may help. It seems that as a group admin in order for an app to get the group data you must first add the app to the group (see: https://www.facebook.com/help/261149227954100). I used to have a groups app that was working great until the lockdown. Now I have no idea if it will work again because the permissions must be reviewed and approved before hand. Very strange workflow to approve the app before it can even be tested.